# Error when try to connect to Replica Set in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

When I try to connect to mongo replica set in AWS I get this error:

> slavenode:27017: [Errno -2] Name or service not
>   known,ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX:27017: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

(where XXX-XX.. corresponds to my actual ip address)

The code to connect is shown below:

```
client = MongoClient("mongodb://Master-PublicIP:27017,Slave-PublicIP:27017/myFirstDB?replicaSet=rs0")
db = client.myFirstDB
try:
    db.command("serverStatus")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
else:
    print("You are connected!")
client.close()
```

(where in Master-PublicIP and Slave-PublicIP I have the actual IPv4 Public IP's from AWS console)

I have already a replica set and the configuration is:

*rs0:PRIMARY> rs.conf()*

```
{
"_id" : "rs0",
"version" : 2,
"members" : [
    {
        "_id" : 0,
        "host" : "ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX:27017",
        "arbiterOnly" : false,
        "buildIndexes" : true,
        "hidden" : false,
        "priority" : 1,
        "tags" : {

        },
        "slaveDelay" : 0,
        "votes" : 1
    },
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "host" : "SlaveNode:27017",
        "arbiterOnly" : false,
        "buildIndexes" : true,
        "hidden" : false,
        "priority" : 1,
        "tags" : {

        },
        "slaveDelay" : 0,
        "votes" : 1
    }
],
"settings" : {
    "chainingAllowed" : true,
    "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
    "getLastErrorModes" : {

    },
    "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
        "w" : 1,
        "wtimeout" : 0
    }
}
```

}

I have create the /data/db in PRIMARY and the /data/db1 in SECONDARY and I have give the proper ownership with `sudo chmod -R 755 /data/db`

My MongoDB version is 3.0.15. Is anyone know what is going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve the problem. As @N3i1 suggests in commnets, I use the Public DNS (IPv4). There was an issue with the hosts that I had declare in  /etc/hosts.

In this file I had define the ips of master/ slaves with some names. For some reason this didn't work. I delete them and then I reconfigure the replica set configuration.

In PRIMARY in mongo shell I did:

```
cfg = {"_id" : "rs0", "members" : [{"_id" : 0,"host" : "Public DNS (IPv4):27017"},{"_id" : 1,"host" : "Public DNS (IPv4):27017"}]}
rs.reconfig(cfg,{force: true});
```

Then I connect in the replica set with python with:

```
MongoClient("mongodb://Public DNS (IPv4):27017,Public DNS (IPv4):27017/?replicaSet=rs0")
```

Of course change the Public DNS (IPv4) adresses with yours.

Comment: glad you sorted it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the `myFirstDB` from within the `MongoClient()`

```
 MongoClient("mongodb://Master-PublicIP:27017,Slave-PublicIP:27017/?replicaSet=rs0")
```

Because your next line then specifies which db you want to use

```
db = client.myFirstDB
```

Or I think you can specify the db by putting a `dot` after the closing brace on the `MongoClient()`

```
MongoClient("mongodb://Master-PublicIP:27017,Slave-PublicIP:27017/?replicaSet=rs0").myFirstDB
```

Comment: Hi @N3i1, I add the line client = MongoClient("mongodb://Master-PublicIP:27017,Slave-PublicIP:27017/?replicaSet=rs0") and I have the same error: slavenode:27017: [Errno -2] Name or service not known,ip-172-31-XX-XX:27017: [Errno -2] Name or service not known. I think if I have another error somewhere else in the configuration but I am not sure where

Comment: From http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/high_availability.html , when i run in python console --> c = MongoClient(replicaset='rs0'); print(c.nodes); sleep(0.1); print(c.nodes) i do not get the nodes (frozenset([]) i get) even if I have connect to mongo with --> c = MongoClient('myhost', 27017). Is there any other way because above link is not very useful

Comment: Have opened port 27017 from within the EC2 Security Group Console

Comment: I I understand right, yes, I have set the Inbound rules -->27017 tcp 0.0.0.0/0 ✔

Comment: No. I have set the rules before the error. This error I think is very suspicious: "slavenode:27017: [Errno -2] Name or service not known". Do you know why the error says "slavenode" while I have declare in /etc/hosts as SlaveNode? With rs.conf() as shown below in my question I have "host" : "SlaveNode:27017"

Comment: case insensitive perhaps https://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/25269-hostname-case-sensitive.html

Comment: The only other thing I could think of without needing to see more config would be to try using your `Public DNS (IPv4)`